# Problem with Basic Terrain Analysis in SAGA

Tags: dem, saga

I am trying to compute LS factor for UAE in SAGA with Basic Terrain Analysis tool, but it always show the same problem "could not initialize data objects".

[image]

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to include the error message as text (images are not  legible on all devices, and cannot be searched by others).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I tried to use Basic Terrain analysis for mosaiced data. The tool works when you use it for each DEM image separately. Then you can mosaic the images in ArcGIS using the mosaic to new raster tool.